# passport.use is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to add passport service to my app , but I am getting the following error, 
I have already installed all the dependencies and tried searching for this error but got none , please Help

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done){         
     TypeError: passport.use is not a function
     at module.exports (/home/udit/Goserv/app/config/passport.js:11:14)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/udit/Goserv/app/server/server.js:9:45)
     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
     at startup (node.js:136:18)
     at node.js:966:3
```

Here is the passport.js file:

```
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

var User = require('../model/user.js');
var config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport){
    var  opts = {};
    opts.secretOrKey =  config.secret;
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done){
        User.find({id: jwt_payload.id}, function(err, user){
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        })
    }));
}
```

Comment: How are you `require`ing your passport.js file?

Comment: You don't have a `passport` variable defined in your file.

Comment: var passport = require('../config/passport')('passport');

Comment: Even if i define the variable here I'm still getting the error! Shall i add server.js code too??

Comment: check if this helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931288/passport-js-throwing-undefined-is-not-a-function-with-localstrategy

Comment: Cant get it to work

Comment: @Udit you are passing a _string_ containing the word `'passport'` to your module, instead of a reference to the `passport` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require passport.js from your app.js file with the following command:

```
require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

All the passport-related commands in your app.js file should be:

```
const passport = require('passport');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

Answer (score 8):

you will get this error if import it like this

```
import * as passport from 'passport';
```

should be

```
import passport from 'passport';
```